# How to pass 2D array from function to main?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to return back a 2D array from function to main. I have 1 main stack and 2 functions. I parse 2D array from main() to function using pointer of pointer data type whose memory is dynamically allocated using malloc.

```
float determinant(float [][200], int);
float** inverse(float [][200], int);
float** transpose(float [][200], float [][200], float);
float** getFloatArray(int);
void printSquareMatrix(float**,int);

double main()
{
    int size = 10;
    float dummyMatrix[200][200];
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        for(j=0;j<size;j++){
            dummyMatrix[i][j] = someMatrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    float **inverseB;
    inverseB = getFloatArray(size);
    inverseB = inverse(dummyMatrix,size);
    printf("%f",inverseB[0][0]); //segfault happened here why?
}

float** getFloatArray(int size)
{
    int i;
    float** arr;
    arr = malloc(sizeof(float*)*size);
        for(i=0;i<size;i++){
            arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(float*)*size);
        }
    return arr;
}
float** inverse(float num[200][200], int yyy){
    /*some codes here*/

    float **retMatrix;
    retMatrix = getFloatArray(yyy);
    retMatrix = transpose(num, fac, f);//the inverse function calls transpose function()
    printf("Print retMatrix");
    return retMatrix //this will be returned to main function 
}

float** transpose(float num[200][200], float fac[200][200], float r){
    /*some code*/
    float **transposeReturn;
    transposeReturn = getFloatArray((int)r);
    printf("Print transposeReturn");

    return transposeReturn; //this will be returned to inverse() function
}
```

The flow of the data is: 2D array is parsed to inverse() and within inverse(), transpose() is called and the 2D array is parsed to transpose for processing, and got return back to inverse() to be processed further before the final 2D array is parsed back to main().

As it can be seen, that both transpose() and inverse() are interchanging 2D array, and it work just fine. It always fails right at when I want to test by printing the inverseB 2D array (after inverse() function is called). I have been contemplating for 2 days straight to find any enlightenment, so far I got nothing.

Do you know what happened here?

Full code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

float determinant(float [][200], int);
float** inverse(float [][200], int);
float** transpose(float [][200], float [][200], float);
float** getFloatArray(int);
void printSquareMatrix(float**,int);


double main()
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int horison = 2, nCons = 3, biggerthan = 1;
    int M = 10000000;

    double A[3][6] = {{2.,1.,1.,0.,0.,0.},
                      {1.,1.,0.,1.,0.,0.},
                      {1.,2.,0.,0.,-1.,1}};

    double b[3]    = {20,18,12};
    double c[6]    = {5.,4.,0,0,0,-M};

    /*Size of the basic solution*/
    int basicSize = biggerthan+nCons /*1+3 = 4*/;
    int nonbasicSize = horison /*the originial variables = 2 (x1 and x2)*/;

    int row = nCons /*3*/;
    int column = basicSize+nonbasicSize /*6*/;

    /*Finding the column index that contains basic variable*/
    int size = 0;
    //Dynamic memory allocation to indexBasic array type int

    int *indexBasic = malloc(sizeof(int*)*size);
    int sumColumn;
    int counter=0;
    for(i=column-basicSize;i<column;i++){
        sumColumn=0;
        for(j=0;j<row;j++)  { 
            sumColumn = sumColumn + A[j][i];
            }
        if (sumColumn==1)         {
            size ++ 
            indexBasic[counter]= i;
            printf("%d\n",indexBasic[counter]);
            counter ++;
            }
        }
    /*Initialise new matrix square B which is taken from the basic vars column of Matrix A*/
    double B[size][size];

    for (i=0;i<size;i++) {
        for (j=0;j<size;j++) {
            B[i][j] = A[i][indexBasic[j]];
            }
    }

    /*Find the inverse of matrix B ~ will call determinant function*/
    float dummyMatrix[200][200];
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        for(j=0;j<size;j++){
            dummyMatrix[i][j] = B[i][j];
            }
        }

    /*Calling determinant of the B matrix*/
    float det = determinant(dummyMatrix,size);
    printf("determinant: %f\n\n",det);

    float **inverseB;
    inverseB = getFloatArray(size);
    inverseB = inverse(dummyMatrix,size);

    printf("\nsegfault start from here?\n");
    printf("%f",inverseB[0][0]);
    for (i=0;i<size;i++);{
        for(j=0;j<size;j++){
            printf("%f ",inverseB[i][j]);
            }
        printf("%s","\n");
        }
    return 0;
}

/*For calculating Determinant of the Matrix */

float determinant(float a[200][200], int xxx){
    float s = 1, det = 0, b[200][200];
    float k = (float) xxx;
    int i, j, m, n, c;

    if (k == 1){
        return (a[0][0]);
        }

    else{
        det = 0;
        for (c = 0; c < k; c++){
            m = 0;
            n = 0;
            for (i = 0;i < k; i++){
                for (j = 0 ;j < k; j++){
                    b[i][j] = 0;
                    if (i != 0 && j != c){
                        b[m][n] = a[i][j];
                        if (n < (k - 2))
                            n++;
                        else{
                            n = 0;
                            m++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            det = det + s * (a[0][c] * determinant(b, k - 1));
            s = -1 * s;
            }
        }
    return det;
}

float** inverse(float num[200][200], int yyy)
{

    float b[200][200], fac[200][200];
    float f = (float)yyy;
    int p, q, m, n, i, j;
    for (q = 0;q < f; q++){
        for (p = 0;p < f; p++){
            m = 0;
            n = 0;
            for (i = 0;i < f; i++){
                for (j = 0;j < f; j++){
                    if (i != q && j != p){
                        b[m][n] = num[i][j];
                        if (n < (f - 2))
                        n++;
                    else{
                        n = 0;
                        m++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
          fac[q][p] = pow(-1, q + p) * determinant(b, f - 1);
        }
    }

    int rowRet = (int)f;
    float **retMatrix;
    retMatrix = getFloatArray(rowRet);/*creating 1D array memory allocaton */

    retMatrix = transpose(num, fac, yyy);

    printf("Print matrix ke 2\n");
    printSquareMatrix(retMatrix,rowRet);
    return retMatrix;
}

/*Finding transpose of matrix*/
float** transpose(float num[200][200], float fac[200][200], float r)
{
    int i, j;
    float b[200][200], inverse[200][200], d;
    for (i = 0;i < r; i++){
        for (j = 0;j < r; j++){
            b[i][j] = fac[j][i];
            }
        }
        d = determinant(num, r);
        for (i = 0;i < r; i++){
            for (j = 0;j < r; j++){
                inverse[i][j] = b[i][j] / d;
                }
            }

    /*Declaring 2D-Array with dynamic allocation memory*/
    int indexRow = (int)r;
    int indexCol = (int)r;
    float **transposeReturn;
    transposeReturn = getFloatArray(r);

    printf("Print matrix ke 1\n");
    for (i=0;i<r;i++){
        for(j=0;j<r;j++){
            transposeReturn[i][j] = inverse[i][j];
            }
        }
    printSquareMatrix(transposeReturn,r);
    return transposeReturn;
}

float** getFloatArray(int size)
{
    int i;
    float** arr;
    arr = malloc(sizeof(float*)*size);
        for(i=0;i<size;i++){
            arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(float*)*size); /*for each element in the memory address, create number of r of integer*/
        }
    return arr;
}

void printSquareMatrix(float** matrix,int size)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i=0;i<size;i++){
        for (j=0;j<size;j++){
            printf("%f ",matrix[i][j]);
            }
         printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: On normal systems [the `main` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function) *must* be declared to return an `int`.

Comment: `float **` types do not refer to a 2-dimensional array, but to an array of `float *` pointers that refer to completely separate 1-dimensional arrays of `float` values.  You can not pass a `float **` value to a function that expects to receive an actual 2-dimensional array such as your `float** transpose(float num[200][200], float fac[200][200], float r)`.  `float num[200][200]` is an actual 2-dimensional array and if you pass a `float **` as `num` your program will fail.

Comment: You need to start by getting a standard compliant compiler, enable maximum warnings, then read all those warnings. There are way too many C language violations in this code that will not pass silently on any known compiler in the world. Rather than to ask me to be your compiler, compile the code yourself.

Comment: Thanks for all the constructing inputs. I managed to overcome this problem by declaring the address of the 2D array in the main and parse it to the function stack, instead of creating the address in the function stack. Thanks a lot.